# Not able to change time format for KeyboardTimePicker in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, date, material-ui

Recently I have started learning React and I am trying to add KeyboardTimePicker from Material UI in my React application.  But it is throwing  error stating that time format is incorrect.
 I need to save the time format as for example 03:30 PM .  Can somebody point out what i am doing wrong here.

Here what I have tried so far

```
class Form extends Component {
        state = {         
        service_req_time: moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A') // Intended to save time format as 03:30 PM

    }

    formatTime(date){

        if (date){
            var amOrPm = (date.getHours() < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
            return date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" + (date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0")) + " " + amOrPm;

        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }

        render() {


        const { service_req_time } = this.state;

        return (



                    <SubForm
                        handleChangeTime={(date)=> this.setState({service_req_time: this.formatTime(date)})}                        
                        service_req_time={service_req_time}

                    />


            );


    }

}
```

// SubForm

```
import 'date-fns';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';


import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

export default class SubForm extends Component {

    render() {

        const {handleChangeTime, service_req_time } = this.props;
        return (

            <div>
                <h1>Select date and time</h1>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <Grid container  justify="space-around">

                        <KeyboardTimePicker
                            margin="normal"

                            id="mui-pickers-time"
                            placeholder="08:00 AM"
                            label="Select time"
                            value={service_req_time}


                            onChange={handleChangeTime}
                            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                'aria-label': 'Select time',
                            }}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `format` prop on the `KeyboardTimePicker`

```
<KeyboardTimePicker
  margin="normal"
  id="mui-pickers-time"
  placeholder="08:00 AM"
  label="Select time"

  format="hh:mm A"

  value={service_req_time}
  onChange={handleChangeTime}
  KeyboardButtonProps={{'aria-label': 'Select time',}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems *moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A')* returns a String, but the time picker expects a date.
Try to use something like this instead: *moment(new Date(), 'hh:mm A')*.